# How to add vertices to an object?

Tags: vertices

I somehow managed to delete some of my vertices, as shown in the picture below. Hitting ctrl-z doesn't work.. Is there an easy way of adding those vertices again? I need them to be shaped like the other existing vertices in the sphere.

[image]

Comment: You can select them and use the fill tool.

Comment: As the symmetry seems to be kept. Duplicate the vertices, rotate 180° and remove doubled vertices... or add a new sphere of the same size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image] Just select the half and delete and mirror the rest of the half

Comment: Yes, it will fill when select the red mark. But how do I go from there to add the vertices symmetrical to those in the sphere?

Comment: can you attach the file

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2856" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2856/)

Comment: answer is updated

Comment: Posting a gif is a supplementary aid to confirm/recap your idea. For a good post, please include all relevant steps as text. Thanks @ateks

Answer (score 1):

Use the symmetry:

In edit mode, duplicate all the vertices, and rotate 180° (be sure to have the 3D cursor set at your object's origin), then remove doubled vertices (tune the merge distance if needed).

[image]